# Getting "Message: h is null"

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've recently encountered something I've never seen before while using `selenium`.

The code (quite simple and straightforward):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.drugs.com/drug-class/laxatives.html?condition_id=&generic=0&sort=rating&order=desc") 

print driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").text
```

Here is a stack trace of the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a/p/SO/selenium_scripts/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print driver.find_element_by_tag_name("title").text
  File "/Users/a/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 328, in find_element_by_tag_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/a/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 664, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/a/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/a/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: h is null
```

Using Firefox 37.0 and selenium 2.45.0.

---

Observations:

- if I switch to `webdriver.Chrome()` - I don't see any errors
- if I use a different URL, e.g. `https://google.com` - I don't see any errors
- I've tried to explicitly wait for search results to be visible before making any further actions, but I still get the same error, code I've used:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.drugs.com/drug-class/laxatives.html?condition_id=&generic=0&sort=rating&order=desc") 

  # wait for the table list to load
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.data-list")))
  ```
- it is not easily googleable which probably means it is web-site specific, but, as noted before, no errors in Chrome

---

Where is the error coming from and what can I do to prevent/fix it? Does this mean I cannot browser/locate elements on this particular web page using selenium+firefox?

Comment: Does  selenium 2.45.0 even support ff 37? Looking at the change log (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG), selenium 2.44 supported FF33. Selenium 2.45 was released around Feb 26th 2015, while FF37 was released on March 31st 2015.

Comment: @Amey yeah, that makes sense, I'll try downgrading firefox and report back. Thanks!

Comment: was just going to suggest a firefox compatibility issue, but it looks like it has already been suggested.   Firefox has the "best compatibility" with Selenium, and at the same time, it has the worst, since compatibility is so heavily pigeon-holed into versions of each.

Comment: @Amey that was it! **Downgrading Firefox** to 36 didn't help, but **to 35.0.1** worked, no errors like that anymore. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @aholt yeah, I suspected it is a selenium-firefox compatibility issue since tackled with them before but decided to post a question in case anyone would experience an error like this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `selenium 2.45.0 does not support ff 37`.

The [change log](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG) shows selenium 2.44 supported FF33. Selenium 2.45 was released around Feb 26th 2015, while FF37 was released on March 31st 2015.

Comment: Confirming. Downgrading to Firefox 35.0.1 helped to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like by the time the page loads it is executing this line of code and throwing an error message.
 try to wait till the page loads by using

```
time.sleep(200)
```

and keep this line of code under try block as:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.data-list")))
except:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: Nope, as I noted in the question, I've tried to add an explicit wait and got the same error. Anyway, the issue is resolved, it was due to compatibility issues between firefox and selenium. Thanks.