# Bokeh Error: h is null

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, python-3.6

I'm following this tutorial : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/interactive-data-visualization-library-python-bokeh/

And this is my code (Bokeh 0.12.6, sklearn 0.18.2, and Python 3.6):

```
from bokeh.charts import BoxPlot, output_file, show
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
df.columns=['petal_width','petal_length','sepal_width','sepal_length']
df =  pd.read_csv("Datasets/iris/iris.csv")
data = df[['sepal_length', 'petal_length']]
p = BoxPlot(data, width=400, height=400)
output_file("boxplot.html", title="box plot example")
show(p)
```

But when I run it, it gives this error:

[image]

I've tried google it, and it leads to this question:

[Getting "Message: h is null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176820/getting-message-h-is-null)

But first, I'm not running selenium here, just bokeh, and I think downgrading firefox is not the best solution (at least in my case), is it a bug in Bokeh?

Hope anybody here can help, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is nearly two years old, and alot can change in two years. The high level `bokeh.charts` API mentioned there has recently been moved to a separate repo. After the next release of Bokeh, the old `bokeh.charts` will have to be explicitly installed and imported as `bkcharts`. However, While core Bokeh is very well supported and maintained, the old charts API should be considered ***completely unmaintained and abandoned*** (there is simply no one to do the work). I would not recommend anyone use `bokeh.charts` for any purpose today.

If you are looking a high-level API on top of Bokeh, you should turn to Holoviews:

http://holoviews.org/

It is:

- officially endorsed by the Bokeh project as a high level API
- already surpasses the old `bokeh.charts` in every way
- has extensive and fantastic documentation
- and most importantly: has an active team maintaining it

Comment: oh.. I see.., I've read about holoviews before but I never considered it. I thought Bokeh is enough, now I should consider to use it. Thank you

Comment: Bokeh is also fine to use, the `bokeh.plotting` API is stable and well-maintained. It's at a slightly lower level. If that suits your needs, core Bokeh is a very good choice. It's *only* the one specific `bokeh.charts` portion of bokeh  that is no longer maintained. But if you want a "very high level" API then Holoviews is a great choice, and is built on top of Bokeh.